# Prevent Windows System %PATH% from being prepended to user %PATH?

Tags: windows-7, windows, path, environment-variables

I know how to set system or user specific environment variables:

[image: Windows Environment Variables]

Now, the problem is that the `PATH` variable is treated such that the value you enter for the user PATH will be *automatically appended* to the system PATH and that will be the effective PATH variable.

That is, say I have

(SYSTEM) `PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Foo\bin;...`

and (USER) `PATH=C:\Program Files\Bar\bin` (note that there is not `%PATH%` in this value)

then the resulting environment variable for this user will be:

(effective) `PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Foo\bin;...;C:\Program Files\Bar\bin`

However, I would rather like that for a very specific OS user account the PATH environment variable should have the `bar\bin`directory at the beginning of the PATH instead of at the end.

**Is there a proper way to tell windows to completely override the `PATH` variable of a user with the value for that user instead of appending it to the system `PATH`variable?**

Note: Obviously, from a batch file, all this doesn't matter as you can set and tweak the env.vars as you like.

Comment: Why not just ignore the USER section. Delete the USER Path variable and put everything into the SYSTEM Path variable, in the order you wish it to be.

Comment: @KevinFegan: Well, because some services on the machine depend on *that* SYSTEM `PATH` and this specific user account would better be served by having a different `PATH`. I know that there are a lot of workarounds, but I was interested whether there is anything out of the box / on the OS/registry level to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need this to work for command prompt sessions, create a profile/init batch file and configure it in the registry, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/how-to-run-a-command-on-command-prompt-startup-in-windows. E.g.,

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun ^
  /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%"USERPROFILE"%\init.cmd" /f
```

Then simply make modifications to the PATH in that batch file. E.g.,

```
SET USER_PATH=c:\whatever
SET PATH=%USER_PATH%;%PATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

You can get "user path variable" through:

```
>reg query HKCU\Environment /v path
```

The output (on my machine) is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    path    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin
```

But then you have to parse this and use the relevant part.

I read the solution here [here](https://superuser.com/questions/615209/access-modify-the-user-path-variable-not-system-path) and tested on my machine.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to ignore system variable, but I know that if you use session variables (via `SET` command), they take precedence over other variables.
So you can use `SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Bar\bin` instruction and your desired path will be the first part of the variable.

[Here](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) is a valid reference, and I report here a simple period from that page:

> If variables with the same name are stored as both User and Machine Environment variables, the user variable will take precedence. If a Session variable is created that will take precedence over any User and/or Machine Environment variable with the same name.

Comment: That’s a useful reference, but the first sentence that you quoted is an overgeneralization.  The `PATH` variable is an exception (special case) — the user variable *does **not*** take precedence over the system variable.  The fact that a “session variable” will take precedence over both user & system pre-set variables is true, but how do you *set* a session variable automatically for a user?  [G-Wiz has answered that question](https://superuser.com/q/367194/150988#1240846), and, AFAICS, you haven’t added anything to that answer.